# What does the question mark at the end of a function name do?

Tags: typescript

I just ran into the following typescript code

```
class Foo {
    start?(): void {}
}
```

Notice the `?` at the end `start`

It seems that it makes that function optional (how can a function be optional and why should you need something like that), because now I have to do

```
const x = new Test();
x.start!();
```

notice the `!` at the end of `start`

So my question is, what exactly is that question mark doing here?

Comment: Read about [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) in the TypeScript handbook.

Comment: "because now I have to do" --- you don't _have to_, instead you could have written safe code and check before you call.

Comment: @axiac I checked the link, but there is nothing mentioned about optional functions

Comment: @zerkms true, but that doesn't change my question :) How/why can a function be optional?

Comment: A property is a property. It does not matter if you keep numbers, strings, objects or functions in it (in fact, the functions are also objects). A `?` after the property name makes it optional.

Comment: Of course it is. And, on the same time, it is a property of the instance that stores a reference to that "method" (which is just a regular JavaScript function, nothing more). Take a look at this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG9oChqehALmATjgBQCUAXNAG7wCWAJihls8PAHYTwgCmAdCPADmRAOQA5eAHdoAT3gBXbN27QAtn168RJANxNMAXz0G0aVhxzQAHhQRIAvNDbdpdvVd64CxXaY9fCaEdSIIA+aHNOHn4hIgAiCWk5RTp2ERw43388QlIdIA

Comment: Yes I see that now, thnx for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an optional property, with a value of function, if a value is set.

It's (more or less) shorthand for this:

```
{
    start: (() => void) | undefined
}
```

That means that the `start` property may or may not have a function as its value. Which means that if you want to call that function, you want to handle the case where it doesn't exist:

```
if (foo.start) {
  foo.start()
}
```

Or with the [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) which is the inverse of the optional property operator:

```
foo.start?.()
```

You should avoid using the `!` postfix operator in most circumstances, because it forces typescript to allow a potentially unsafe operation. If the property really is `undefined`, then forcing your way through to calling it anyway would throw a runtime error.

---

Here's a more complete example:

```
class Foo {
  start?(): void

  constructor(isStartable: boolean) {
    if (isStartable) {
      this.start = () => console.log('starting!')
    }
  }
}

const nonStartable = new Foo(false)
// Will not call the start method.
if (nonStartable.start) nonStartable.start()

const startable = new Foo(true)
// Will call the start method.
if (startable.start) startable.start()

// If you run this code "starting!" is logged exactly once.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa0IBcwCccB+ACgEoAuaAN3gEsATDDLYeAO13wFdgd58JOhADKeQmABGIAKZVJiWWHZkULLNDoAzaENHi80marSYNWHAAthAOlwEc0ALy7VTgHzQ2neLJsh4AHMSAHJ7Qjp2QIBCELJ1LABfdWT0VIxvXGh2DjEHKVlnbJkAdzhEEi0wEAhjDAB6eugAdToQEGz4R2BqjqsZbANoAFsZK3gGGwwc9jyJIzsDIhtyZnRMx3DDQpd2UvL4EhweOvRGlraOnvbofsGHEbHLCan0LYKZRYdl1fQGpoAkjoAJ7wbjQHjsW7WGBsBgDABEW0iMQRmhgAUCgRkDGgMgAHmA+CBgdAOMBPkA)

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer, it makes sense now!